# GridView is not allowing to find any control

Tags: html, vb.net, gridview, nested

I want to use nested gridview. But my Parent Grid is showing `Nothing` in ChildGrid's variable.

Any help? I've tried following ways:

1)

> Dim gvChild As GridView =
>   CType(Me.gvwSubjectForProject.FindControl("gvChildGrid"), GridView)

2)

> Dim gvChild As GridView =
>   Me.gvwSubjectForProject.FindControl("gvChildGrid")
>                           gvChild.DataSource = dt_Subject
>                           gvChild.DataBind()

I want to find Child grid's id and then want to assign it data source.

### VB

> Private Function FillGrid(ByVal mode As String, ByVal dt_Subject As
>   DataTable) As Boolean
>           'Dim dt_Subject As DataTable = Nothing
>           'Dim dt_sortsubject As DataTable = Nothing
>           Try
>
> ```
>         If (mode = "ParentGrid") Then
>             Me.gvwSubjectForProject.DataSource = Nothing
>             Me.gvwSubjectForProject.DataBind()
>             'Me.ViewState(VS_CurrentSubject) = Nothing
>             Me.btnExport.Visible = False
>
>             'dt_Subject.Columns.Add("Status", GetType(String))
>             If Not dt_Subject Is Nothing Then
>                 If dt_Subject.Rows.Count > 0 Then
>                     If dt_Subject.Rows.Count > 0 Then
>                         For Each dr_Row In dt_Subject.Rows
>                             If dr_Row("cStatus") = "AC" Then
>                                 dr_Row("Status") = "Active"
>                             ElseIf dr_Row("cStatus") = "IA" Then
>                                 dr_Row("Status") = "In Active"
>                             ElseIf dr_Row("cStatus") = "HO" Then
>                                 dr_Row("Status") = "Hold"
>                             ElseIf dr_Row("cStatus") = "SC" Then
>                                 dr_Row("Status") = "Screened"
>                             ElseIf dr_Row("cStatus") = "BO" Then
>                                 dr_Row("Status") = "Booked"
>                             ElseIf dr_Row("cStatus") = "OS" Then
>                                 dr_Row("Status") = "On Study"
>                             ElseIf dr_Row("cStatus") = "FI" Then
>                                 dr_Row("Status") = "Forever Ineligible"
>                             Else
>                                 dr_Row("cStatus") = "Not Found"
>                             End If
>                         Next
>                         Me.btnExport.Visible = True
>                         'Me.ViewState(VS_CurrentSubject) = dt_Subject
>                         Me.gvwSubjectForProject.DataSource = dt_Subject
>                         Me.gvwSubjectForProject.DataBind()
>                     End If
>                 End If
>             End If
>
>         ElseIf (mode = "ChildGrid") Then
>             If Not dt_Subject Is Nothing Then
>                 If dt_Subject.Rows.Count > 0 Then
>
>                     'Me.gvwSubjectForProject.DataSource = dt_Subject
>                     'Me.gvwSubjectForProject.DataBind()
>
>                     'Me.gvwSubjectForProject.FindControl("gvChildGrid").DataSource =
> ```
>
> dt_Subject
>
> ```
>                     'CType(Me.gvwSubjectForProject.FindControl("gvChildGrid"),
> ```
>
> GridView).DataBind()
>                           'Me.gvwSubjectForProject.FindControl("gvChildGrid").
>                           'Me.gvwSubjectForProject.FindControl("gvChildGrid").DataBind()
>
> ```
>                     Dim gvChild As GridView = Me.gvwSubjectForProject.FindControl("gvChildGrid")
>                     gvChild.DataSource = dt_Subject
>                     gvChild.DataBind()
>                 End If
>             End If
>         End If
>
>         Return True
>
>     Catch ex As Exception
>         Me.ShowErrorMessage("Error While Binding Grid", "....FillGrid")
>         Return False
>     End Try
> End Function
> ```

## HTML NESTED GRIDVIEW

```
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlgvwSubjectStatus" runat="server" Style="max-height: 500px; overflow: auto;
            width: 60%;">
            <asp:GridView ID="gvwSubjectForProject" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                SkinID="grdViewSmlAutoSize" Width="70%" ShowFooter="true" AllowPaging="true"
                PageSize="1">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnExpand" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/Plus.gif" alt="Expand"
                                OnClientClick="imgbtnExpand_Click" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hcStatus" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("cStatus") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="STATUS">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="true" Width="40%" />
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="true" Width="40%" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="max-height: 300px; width: 100%; overflow: auto;
                                text-align: right;">
                                <%--<asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Width="100%">--%>
                                    <asp:GridView ID="gvChildGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" SkinID="grdViewSmlAutoSize">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="40%" DataField="vSubjectID" HeaderText="SUBJECT ID">
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="true" Width="40%" />
                                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="true" Width="40%" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="60%" DataField="FullName" HeaderText="FULL NAME">
                                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="true" Width="60%" />
                                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="true" Width="60%" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                <%--</asp:Panel>--%>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalSubject" HeaderText="TOTAL SUBJECTS">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="true" Width="50%" />
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="true" Width="50%" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </asp:Panel>
```

And one more thing, in HTML when child gridview is not displayed, its still filling  while creating its DOM. I want to delete that blank space too.

Comment: Please post all of your code for the event method that you are doing these attempted `FindControl()` calls within. Also, could you please post the markup for the nested grid view controls?

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code is not working, because you are using the `FindControl()` method on the entire parent grid view control instead of on an individual row in the grid view control, like this:

Find child grid view in `OnRowDataBound` event:

```
Sub ParentGridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    ' Only look for child grid view in data rows, ignore header and footer rows
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim theChildGridView As GridView = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("gvChildGrid"), GridView)

        ' Do something with theChildGridView here

    End If
End Sub
```

Find child grid view by looping through all rows in parent grid view control:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In ParentGridView.Rows
    ' Only look for child grid view in data rows, ignore header and footer rows
    If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim theChildGridView As GridView = DirectCast(row.FindControl("gvChildGrid"), GridView)

        ' Do something with theChildGridView here
    End If
Next
```

Comment: But atleast there shold be any way to get control of Child_gridview in Parent_gridview... Even imgbtnExpand can not b found while debugging.

Comment: Ok. I'll try this way, but meanwhile can you help me with my other problem that I stated in last sentence in my question?

Comment: Problem seems like in 

<templateField>
<ItemTemplate>.....CHILD GRID.....</ItemTemplate>
</templateField>

'cz even when child grid is not fetched, templatefield is transformed in <td></td>